# Delphi - How do you resolve a conflict when a unit name is the same as a property name?

Tags: delphi, scope, delphi-2007

The trivial example below is a condensation of a problem I had trying to resolve a conflict where I had an enumerated type member with the same name as a VCL member.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
    TSomeType = (
      alNone,
      alSome,
      alMany) ;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
Self.Align := alNone ;                    // 1.  type mismatch
Self.Align := Controls.alNone ;           // 2.  "Controls" is also a property of TForm
end ;

end.
```

- The first assignment fails because the compiler thinks `alNone` is the one I declared and not the `TAlign` member defined in `Controls.pas`.
- The second one fails because it took `Controls` to mean the `TForm` property of that name.

I realise there are ways around this (renaming the `alNone` member being the simplest), but I'm curious as to whether there is a way of qualifying a reference to a property in another unit where the *unit name* conflicts with an identifier in the current scope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Qualify it with the type name:

```
TAlign.alNone
```

I had not realised when I wrote this that the compiler version was relevant. This syntax only became available in Delphi 2010 or XE. There the answer is not appropriate for the tagged version, Delphi 2007. Deltics answer covers much more detail.

Comment: Personally I always write the enumerated types like this. More meaningful and more common (across different languages).

Comment: @ross - How were you able to do that with D2007? The one I have complains with *"[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(33): E2018 Record, object or class type required"*.

Comment: That's interesting, I was sure that syntax was always available, but you are quite right

Comment: @Sertac - I had already fixed the issue by choosing a non-conflicting name, and hadn't tried qualifying it with the type name.

Answer (score 6):

As David's answer suggests, for an enum type or other situation where a type can be used to qualify the identifier involved then you can of course simply use the type name as required:

```
someAlign  := TAlign.alNone;
someMyType := TMyType.alNone;
```

This use of enums is referred to as "[scoped enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi))" and is not supported in older versions of the Delphi compiler.  I believe **XE2** may have been when it was introduced.  Certainly this was the version that made scoping enums in this way mandatory by default.

Though it can be turned off via a compiler directive.  When turned off, you can still use scoped enums but you are not *required* to.

In versions that support this, you **must** qualify any enums that are defined while this is turned on.  You can choose whether to quality or not when using enums that are defined when this is turned off.

```
type
{$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
TFoo = (Black, White);  // MUST qualify:  eg. "TFoo.Black"

{$SCOPEDENUMS OFF}
TBar = (Black, White);  // MAY qualify or not if/as needed
```

For older versions of Delphi without scoped enum support, or in situations where the identifier is *not* an enum member and cannot otherwise be qualified by type - for example if your identifiers conflict with some *unit*-level identifier (e.g. such as `mrOk`, in **Controls**) then you need to a little bit more work, but not much.

In these cases, simply define a new constant to create an unambiguous "local alias" for the constant in the other unit, and introduce this where the unit name is unambiguous.  Similar to:

```
  type
    TMyResult = (
      mrOk,
      mrFailed) ;

  const
    Controls_mrOk = Controls.mrOk;  // mrOk is a const, not an enum member
```

Comment: XE allows TAlign.alNone, 2007 does not. Docs date back to [2010](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/e/index.php?title=Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)&action=history). Probably it was XE or 2010.